# Map & Filter for Returning Elements from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to learn to use map, reduce, and filter. I've looked on MDN, but the documentation leaves me feeling confused.

I'm trying to use map to return a new array of player's names. I'm also trying to use filter to make an array with players from a single team.

```
const athletes= [{
    name: 'Peter',
    sport: 'baseball',
    league: 'varsity',
    team: 'Rangers',
}, {
    name: 'Jon',
    sport: 'football',
    league: 'little',
    team: 'Cowboys',
}];
```

Here's what I have for using map for an array of names:

```
listPlayers = function(name) {
    // console.log(athletes[name]);
    return name;
}

athletes.map(listPlayers);
```

Bonus question: What learning resources should I use after Javascript for Kids?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `Here's what I have for using map for an array of names:` and? what's the problem? you need to describe what you expect, your code has no errors as such, it's just not doing what you expect probably

Comment: this `listPlayers = function({name}) {` is what you probably wanted - but `athletes.map(listPlayers);` simply maps the array and immediately discards the result anyway ... you're not saving the newly created array anywhere

Comment: `Bonus question` - bonus answer, don't ask SO for external resources :p

Comment: `athletes.filter(({team}) => team === searchTeam).map(({name}) => name)`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use map to return a new array of player's names.

Okay. The callback function in `map()` is going to receive one item from the array you're mapping. So you're function should look more like this:

```
listPlayers = function(athlete) {
    return athlete.name;
}
```

With each athlete passed in you're returning the name. So:

```
athletes.map(listPlayers)
//[ 'Peter', 'Jon' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

map function should use with callback with params every iter is current item(like for loop):

```
var athletesNames = athletes.map( function(athlete){
  return athlete.name;
});
```

item synthax for filter, return `true` for item you want to pick:

```
var athletesTeamRangers = athletes.filter( function(athlete){
  return athlete.team === 'Rangers';
});
```